# What should be the value of VisitorId for Recommendations AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Are there specific requirements for the VisitorID value (max length or maybe it should be composed only from numbers...)? If we send for ex. "visitor76a008b9d38491ff142774559e740552" it will work?

[image]

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work since your string input for `visitorID` is 39 bytes. Field [visitorID](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.catalogs.eventStores.userEvents#userinfo) has a length limit of 128 bytes and there are no input restrictions. As long as the string input is within the said limit it should be fine.

> **visitorID** -> string
>
> Required. A unique identifier for tracking visitors with a length
> limit of 128 bytes.
>
> For example, this could be implemented with a http cookie, which
> should be able to uniquely identify a visitor on a single device. This
> unique identifier should not change if the visitor log in/out of the
> website. Maximum length 128 bytes. Cannot be empty.